# where is _md5 module code located in the system?

Tags: python

I was reading [hashlib.py](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/hashlib.py) code and I saw it `import _md5` on line 78.

I found the `hashlib.py` file in `/usr/lib/python2.7` but I can't find the `_md5` module.

Where can I find the code of `_md5` module ?

Comment: why you want _md5 file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python conventionally files that begin with an underscore are meant to be "special", here it means the file has been compiled through C and therefore there's no python code to be found for the "md5 hash algorithm".

If you want to inspect the source code of that module, check it out from here: https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Modules/md5.c